# Is it possible to remove a superclass' IBInspectable property?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm writing a **custom view** that inherits from another (think of a CustomButton that inherits from UIButton).

The superclass (UIButton) has a few properties which can be inspected using the Interface Builder's inspector (such as the font, color etc.).

I want my custom class to display **only my own inspectable properties**, and abstract the lower-level options (from UIButton) that will be overwritten by my class anyway.

**Is it possible to remove the IBInspectable properties from a superclass?**

Comment: No, since you can't override a property in a subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like if you want to extend UIView class and remove background attribute from Interface Builder. That's not possible from structure.

Then, if you try to override font attribute in your inherited UIButton class for customization (as code below), you'll receive compiler errors because you cannot override a stored property of super class.

```
override var font: UIFont {
    set {

    }
    get {

    }
}
```

Comment: So, no :( Anyway, I guess if I don't care so much about the methods I could extend UIView directly and add the UIButton as a subview to achieve the same thing visually.